# Create a .NET installer on Visual Studio macOS for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I’m trying to create an installer for an ASP.NET MVC application on Visual Studio for Mac but I'm stuck at the installation of the `Visual Studio Installer Projects` extension.

I’ve been following the instructions to use the Visual Studio Installer Projects extension, but I’m unable to find it in the extension manager. I’ve also tried using the VSIX file, but it doesn’t seem to work either.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.